# Recompiling iOS app to publish on Apple store

Tags: ios

I have published iOS app on Apple Store.
It was compiled on developer's MAC computer.

Now I need to figure out how to recompile on different MAC computer to publish on Apple store.

Can I use existing certificate
or
do I have to create new certificate?

I just want to publish newer version of my application.

What do I need from developer?

By the way, I have full access to Apple Developer's account.

Thanks,
Ashok

Answer (score 1):

You would require private key, certificate, and provisioning profile along with access to apple developer account for publishing your app.

Since you already have access to the developer account, so provisioning profile and certificate is no issue.
So in fact you just have to private key from the developer.

FYI: private key and digital certificate[contains public key] are together known as signing identity.

Comment: Is that visible on Developer account?  And once I get it, what do I need to do?

Comment: If developer does not give me private key, what are my options?

Comment: If your application is not published than its better to revoke certificate and generate new pair. Other wise you should check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1868/_index.html

Comment: I first deployed my App on Aug 11, 2014.  So it looks like I can create 2nd Certificate while the 1st one remains active.  Only thing is that I am new to MAC (have to borrow my friend's MAC to do this) and it may be little difficult using Keychain, etc.

Comment: Yes the process is not cake walk for sure. But this topic is very well documented by developer website and tech forums. Also do remember that it almost takes 2 weeks to get review done by apple before you can see your app after submitting in normal case. Have fun.

Comment: Is Keychain tool part of the XCode?

Comment: No it comes as part of mac os by name 'keychain access'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61578/discussion-between-androidashok-and-bllakjakk).

Answer (score 0):

In order to upload the app on app store you will need

1. Production Certificate with private key installed on your MAC.
2. Distribution Provisioning Profile (enabled for App Store ).

Make sure your provisioning profile use the same "App Id" that was used during the last version      uploading process.
   You can check the "app Id" or "bundle Id" on the app detail page of your iTunes account . ( You must have all these configured in your existing account)

Now, if you don't get the private key from your last developer. You can simply log in to iTunes account and can revoke the Production certificate.
You can find several tutorials on web for "Revoking Certificate"

After revoking you can download and install the certificate on your MAC and can also distribute it to other developers in your team. Now, download or create the distribution profile enabled for App Store and install it on your MAC (If it got expired then renew it)

Also, Please refer some tutorial for app uploading process. You will get a better idea on all this.

Comment: I am very new to iOS app development.  I am an expert Android developer.  I think Apple site has everything (instructions) I need.  If you know any easy Tutorial for this, maybe you can share here. Thanks, Ashok

Comment: To Revoke Certificate: http://help.como.com/Submit-My-App/Submit-to-Apple-App-Store/34508100/How-do-I-revoke-my-iOS-Distribution-Certificate-P12-file.htm

Comment: To Upload App- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812